# Diagnosing and Addressing MongoDB Connection Error in Server Configuration

Tags: node.js, mongodb, terminal, connection, mongodb-.net-driver

MongoNetworkError: 2C090000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1586:SSL alert number 80

```
at connectionFailureError (E:\mernestate-push\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:379:20)       
at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (E:\mernestate-push\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:285:22)        
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:634:26)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:519:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)       
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)  
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
```

connectionGeneration: 15,
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'ResetPool' },
[cause]: [Error: 2C090000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1586:SSL alert number 80
] {
library: 'SSL routines',
reason: 'tlsv1 alert internal error',
code: 'ERR_SSL_TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR'
}
}

to solve problem
My server connect to the database

Comment: How do you try to connect? How does your configuration look like?